# Using python-oracledb / cx_oracle to connect to AWS RDS Oracle with TLS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, cx-oracle, python-oracledb

I'm trying to use the [Python oracledb library](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/introduction.html) (successor to cx_oracle) to connect from AWS Lambda to RDS Oracle using TLS. I may want to do mutual TLS, but even one-way TLS would be fine. I could use some help.

What I can do:

- I can connect to RDS Oracle using TLS with SQL Developer on my local PC. I had to add the AWS RDS 2019 root cert to the Java Keystore. I didn't have to use an Oracle wallet.
- I can connect unencrypted from Lambda Python 3.9 to Oracle RDS using python-oracledb in thin mode
- I can connect unencrypted from Python on my PC to Oracle RDS using python-oracledb in thin mode

Noting that this is not a firewall issue, I have opened up the correct ports in AWS.

**Code**

Here's the basics of the code, which is very similar to the [Oracle example](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/easy-way-to-connect-python-applications-to-oracle-autonomous-databases).

```
import oracledb
import sys
import boto3
        
# When creating the Lambda function, ensure the following setting for LD_LIBRARY_PATH
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    ssm_parameter = boto3.client('ssm')
    
    # Unencrypted connection works fine
    # oracleDSN = "dbname.accountstring.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:2484/servicename"
    
    oracleDSN = '''(description= (retry_count=3)(retry_delay=1)(address=(protocol=tcps)
(port=2484)(host=dbname.accountstring.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com))(connect_data=(service_name=servicename))
(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="C=US,ST=Washington,L=Seattle,O=Amazon.com,OU=RDS,CN=dbname.accountstring.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com")))'''

    connRds = oracledb.connect(user=database_user, password=database_password, dsn=oracleDSN)
```

**Errors**

Here's the error message output from lambda (# replaces sensitive information)

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "DPY-6005: cannot connect to database. Connection failed with \"[SSL] internal error (_ssl.c:2633)\"",
  "errorType": "OperationalError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 850, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/TableDailyCount.py\", line 50, in <module>\n    connRds = oracledb.connect(user=database_user, password=database_password, dsn=oracleDSN)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/oracledb/connection.py\", line 1000, in connect\n    return conn_class(dsn=dsn, pool=pool, params=params, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/oracledb/connection.py\", line 128, in __init__\n    impl.connect(params_impl)\n",
    "  File \"src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx\", line 345, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect\n",
    "  File \"src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx\", line 163, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_params\n",
    "  File \"src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx\", line 129, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_description\n",
    "  File \"src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx\", line 247, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_address\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/oracledb/errors.py\", line 103, in _raise_err\n    raise exc_type(_Error(message)) from cause\n"
  ]
}
```

**What I've tried**

- Reading all the docs. I'm very technical and experienced, but fairly new to Python and Oracle.
- Copying the RDS pem root certificate into the deployment package and referencing that as the keystore - that didn't work
- I've added the RDS CA Certs to three different cacerts files within the python39 folder ( C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39) as described on [this page](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fixing-your-ssl-verify-errors-in-python-71c2201db4b2) (you need to register for a free account to see the page)
- I've read everything I can find on the internet about this that seems relevant
- I've tried adding a wallet. I created the wallet in p12 format, added the RDS certs, converted to pem format with openssl (from memory) because the script on the oracledb page didn't work for me. I also tried putting the AWS RDS certs directly into the lambda but that didn't seem to work either. Reference the [AWS certs page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html), ap-southeast-2-bundle.pem.

**Question**

- How would I get single direction TLS working?
- How do you create the ewallet.pem in the format that's required, from the AWS RDS Sydney root certificates?

Comment: Can you get the previous error? The one that caused the exception that we are seeing? That should shed light on the source of the issue. If you are using mTLS, you *will* need the ewallet.pem. You will also need to point to that location with wallet_location and supply the wallet_password if you left ewallet.pem encrypted.

Comment: If you set the environment variable PYO_DEBUG_PACKETS=1 we can see the packet trace as well. That might also shed light on what is going on.

Comment: Here's the documentation on using mTLS with python-oracledb: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#mutual-tls-mtls-connection-to-oracle-autonomous-database it shows the use of a PEM file and the parameters Anthony mentioned for Thin mode.

Comment: You can also open a discussion on the python-oracledb GitHub page (https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/discussions) to see if we can help further.

Comment: Thanks both, appreciated! Great to have a cx dev @AnthonyTuininga ! I have added lots of info and clarified my aims - one way TLS is good, mutual is better. I've added info on how I tried to use a wallet / cert above, pretty sure it's a PEBKAC error. I've posted on the oracledb forum with slightly more info than here https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/discussions/34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in python-oracledb-1.0.1. The latest release 1.0.2 works to connect from both my PC and AWS Lambda to Oracle RDS TLS. The code above works fine.

Anthony from Oracle who posted above was amazingly helpful. Quick to reply to this question, quick with diagnosis, quick to fix the bug, and quick to release a patch. Thanks again Anthony!